# Display 1st row of Dashboard

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-home-page

How to Display the selected dashoboards instead of displaying full dashboard in home page layout in lightning experience

Comment: What do you mean by selected dashboard?

Comment: In lightning App builder if i map dashboard component it is displaying all the dashboards assigned to user. I want to display only few dashboards in lightning home page instead of displaying all the dashboards